# Difference in two pattern of cloudwatch logging to understand pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Lets say I have 10 lines of data with 1000 byte in each line.

What is the difference in cost incurred if I log in the following pattern.

1. All 10 lines is logged in single entity in cloudwatch logs. i.e. only 1 entry is created in it
2. Each of 10 line is logged in single entity in cloudwatch logs. i.e. 10 entry is created in it.

Comment: Cloudwatch pricing is determined on the amount of data in GB. It's 0.50$ for every ingested GB, plus 0.03 $ for every stored GB.

Comment: Should I take this statement as actual data ingested by publisher and there is no other rules applicable?